# Cannot create new user in Alfresco

Tags: java, jsf, alfresco

I build alfresco from source. After I log in into Alfresco Explorer as an admin , I cannot create new user. Any kind help is appreciated.

Comment: any error on the logs? any UI hint of what's not working?

Comment: No error on the logs. As a UI hint, all wizard-like dialogs are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be check out source from alfresco public repository.
So source code has changes in every time by other committed users.
I also face like that your error.Finally I checked out other revision no 32495 from public repository and it is okay for our problems.